# PDF : How a PDF table made by Latex is represented using PDF operators?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I Have a PDF document made by Latex which contains a table.

What are the pdf operators that represents this table ? I think Latex draws the table. right ?

as I want to extract it using PDFBOX library

When I decoded the PDF table I found these lines related to graphical objects and text.
does the line between q and Q draws a lines or 
for the table

[image]

```
stream
q
1 0 0 1 139.746 715.892 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 100.9 0 l S
Q
q
1 0 0 1 139.746 703.738 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 11.955 l S
Q
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 148.795 707.324 Td [(aaaa)]TJ
ET
q
1 0 0 1 186.626 703.738 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 11.955 l S
Q
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 198.277 707.324 Td [(bbbb)]TJ
ET
```

Comment: no, I want to extract the table from the PDF.
that's why I wanna know how it is represented

Comment: Unlike HTML, for example, there is no "table" command in PDF text formatting syntax. It's all "some text" at certain coordinates. -- Isn't PDFbox a Java library?

Comment: yes, it can get the operators and I can process them.
I just need to know the operators that draw this table

Comment: The snippet you added *are* these operators. I can see matrix transformations, lines, and text positions. That's all you're going to get -- nothing like `<table><tr><td>aa..`.

Comment: great. Do you know how to understand the line that draws the lines ?

for ex: []0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 11.955 l S
this could be the answer of my question

Comment: I'd have to look the exact specs up, but I'll let you do that yourself: [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) (I recommend v1.6, *not* the heavily formalized ISO version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the commands can easily be found in [Adobe's PDF Reference 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).

One command at a time, and remembering that PDF has [postfix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), we can find in Chapter 4 "Graphics":

```
q                                   % save graphics state  (§4.2.1)
1 0 0 1 139.746 715.892 cm          % set transform matrix (§4.2.3)
                                    % --this is a simple 'translate' to (139.746,715.892)
[]0 d                               % set dash pattern to solid (§4.3.3)
0 J                                 % set line cap to Butt
0.398 w                             % set line width to 0.398 units
0 0 m                               % move "current point" (§4.4.1)
100.9 0 l                           % append straight line
S                                   % stroke the path (§4.4.2)
Q                                   % restore the graphics state
```

Comment: Can we update width(line) and save in new file?.(To make uniform line widths of existing pdf files)